# How can I create a table in a post?

Tags: support, faq, markdown, editor

I want to create a table to better illustrate my question, but I cannot find any option to do so.

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Answer (score 92):

Tables [have been added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) to Stack Exchange as of December 2020.

This is what you want:

```
|id|name |email|
|--| --- | --- |
|1 | Sta |sta@example.com|
|2 |Danny|dany@example.com|
|3 |Elle |elle@example.com|
```

This will give you a pure HTML table, like this:

| id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | sta@example.com |
| 2 | Danny | dany@example.com |
| 3 | Elle | elle@example.com |

This table is based on the [GitHub-flavored markdown table extension specification](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-).

Details of the feature are included in its announcement in [New Feature: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to provide sample data for your `[sql]`-tagged question, please use common table expression rather than ascii-formatted tables.

```sql
with t (id,name,email) as (values
  (1 ,'Sta'  ,'sta@example.com'),
  (2 ,'Danny','dany@example.com'),
  (3 ,'Elle' ,'elle@example.com')
)
select your_attempt from t
```

Ideally prepared as code snippet on some SQL playground engines such as [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). It makes potential helper's work easier since s/he concentrates on answer instead of text formatting.