# Add Table Generator link as part of the help for writing question/answer for creating tables using markdown

Tags: feature-request, markdown, editor, tables

I found [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) a very helpful tool for generating tables in markdown format. Stack Overflow Help for tables provides some links, but none of them help the user for generating the table. Doing it manually for large tables takes significant time, and people looking for help in SO don't find this link. The **suggestion** is:

1. Provide such a link as part of contextual help or/and SO support pages. (Solution with minimal effort) or
2. **Optimal solution**: as an embedded element (this tool or any other similar one) in the editor for questions/answers to generate the table in markdown format.

At the same time, a significant amount of questions use screenshots or links for sharing tables that would not be necessary if users know about this tool. Sharing this information in the help section/pages or embedding the tool in the editor, may minimize this impact.

[image: current help for tables]

Comment: Just noting that the [Stacks Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380295/1099857) (currently in beta) does not have this embedded help documentation. I'm not sure what the timeline for final release is for the new editor, but I am unsure that making changes to help documentation that is likely being removed is something that will be implemented at this time.

Comment: That said, I would definitely be in favour of something like this either as an external tool or as an embedded element within the editor, _especially_ if it reduced the amount of screenshots of data/tables/frames.

Comment: @HenryEcker embedded would be great, but it requires some implementation effort. That why I started with a simple link. Something with almost cero effort.

Comment: Related [How can I create a table in a post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/1595451) (faq)

Comment: @HenryEcker added the embedded option as an alternative optimal solution.

Comment: *Related*: It is also possible to generate an excel table from an image. [Insert data from picture](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-data-from-picture-3c1bb58d-2c59-4bc0-b04a-a671a6868fd7).This feature is rolling out to Office Insiders running Beta Channel Version 2207 (Build 15402.20002) or later. As an alternative [Extract Table](https://extracttable.com/) (two tables per day for the free version): ). In case it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are in the middle of the roll out process for new Stacks Editor, I considered to post the question in Stack Exchange: [Add Table Generator link as part of the help in SO Editor for generating tables using markdown format or embed it in the SO Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382605/add-table-generator-link-as-part-of-the-help-in-so-editor-for-generating-tables) with the tag [stacks-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stacks-editor) as per instructions here: [Announcing the Stacks Editor Beta release!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380295/announcing-the-stacks-editor-beta-release) to be considered. Since this feature is related to Stacks Editor that is across the board all platforms.

There a previous related feature request in Stack Exchange (more than 2 years ago): [Accessibility and Tables - Could we borrow the markdown used by Jira or similar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345584/accessibility-and-tables-could-we-borrow-the-markdown-used-by-jira-or-similar), suggesting to use [Jira Markdown tool](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=tables). Now this page is just informative, there is no such tool to generate the markdown table now. A moderator provided a comment that they cannot use it:

> Jira is a helpdesk/ticketing software/ We can't use it. In theory, their flavour of markdown could be copied, or allowing html tables could be used but it might be more practical to rescoping this form "can we use (totally different software)" to "Can we borrow the ways that software does it?"  Journeyman Geek [mod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod)

As @HenryEcker pointed in the comments, it is not in the scope of the Stacks Editor new release (currently beta)