# Is using a screenshot and reference link wrong?

Tags: support, answers, disputed-flags

I've recently answered a question with a screenshot from a reference site. It was a table so I pasted a screenshot to preserve styling. I also added the reference site link.

This was downvoted by someone indicating it was a link-only answer. Is that classified as link only answer in SO?

Comment: Could you link to the answer? If it's just a screenshot + a link to the reference, then it's probably not a great answer.

Comment: Yea, this needs some context.

Comment: As long as the image was uploaded to SE's Imgur space and the answer is contained in the image, then it's not, strictly, link-only. *However*, that doesn't mean it's a good answer (or that the image inherently answers the question). Images of text are fairly useless as answers or in questions. It would be **much** better to put the text in the answer *as text* in a blockquote (and, given that it's a table, as a table).

Comment: Related: *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*). It covers answers as well.

Comment: *“It was a table so I pasted a screenshot to preserve styling”* See [How can I create a table in a post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501/2257664).

Comment: Amazed with the number of downvotes just for asking the question, that makes this is a very friendly community.

Comment: Downvotes do nothing here so why are you worried about them? Images are unsuitable for visually impaired people to use and are also not searchable.

Comment: Votes on meta are also used to indicate agreement/disagreement, not just quality. Since meta votes don't affect your reputation or count towards a question ban, that's usually not a big problem.

Comment: The downvotes could well be because of the lacking context...

Comment: Yes, this meta question could have been asked better (hint: it still can be improved).

Comment: It is at the very tippy top of the [faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow) - thou shalt not post pictures of data. Just saying, it might be time to do a little refresher after 12 years of activity. Things change, but it is not exactly uncommon that for long time contributors that happens kind of behind their back because they just keep their head down and mind their own business.

Answer (score 14):

An image on its own is not an answer most of the time. An image can only be used to illustrate visually what the answer is proposing, e.g. a screenshot of an IDE with a button highlighted would be an illustration to an answer explaining that the solution is to click this button and what it does.

An image of a table from a website is definitely not an answer. It's also not a supporting illustration. An answer like this should either be deleted (or flagged to be deleted by mods) or rewritten completely. The answer's author should use their own words to explain the solution to the stated problem. A link can be used at the end of the answer as a supporting reference to the official source.